# Setting margins programmatically isn't working

Tags: android, android-button

I am working on a native Android project using a physical device with android version 4.4.2. I have a button within a vertical linear layout and I want to set the top and bottom margins to 0 programmatically.

Information about the parent view

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams detailParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
LinearLayout detailContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
detailContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
detailContainer.setLayoutParams(detailParams);
```

The button

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams messageParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        messageParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);

    // Displays the message
    Button buttonWithMessage= new Button(this);
    buttonWithMessage.setText(post.getMessage());
    ...
    buttonWithMessage.setLayoutParams(messageParams);
```

Adding the button to the parent view

```
detailContainer.addView(buttonWithMessage);
```

But no matter what values I put in `messageParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);`, the margins don't change. I want the margins to span the whole width except for a little bit at the left and right and none at the top and bottom so it appears to touch. I've even tried setting these same params for every parent view above since the parent views are all linear layouts but still nothing.

Comment: I don´t see you setting the new params to the view after you changed them

Comment: Whoops, accidentally didn't post that, there were some more settings I skipped over

Answer (score 0):

You should use LayoutParams to set your button margins:

```
 LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
 );
 params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
 yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Depending on what layout you're using you should use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams or LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

Comment: I don't think I understand, my example is using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, are you saying I should make it more generic?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams detailParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    LinearLayout detailContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
    detailContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    detailContainer.setLayoutParams(detailParams);

    detailContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams messageParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    messageParams.setMargins(400, 400, 400, 400);

    // Displays the message
    Button buttonWithMessage = new Button(this);
    buttonWithMessage.setText("Hai");
    buttonWithMessage.setTransformationMethod(null);
    //   buttonWithMessage.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
    buttonWithMessage.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    buttonWithMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    buttonWithMessage.setLayoutParams(messageParams);
    detailContainer.addView(buttonWithMessage);
    setContentView(detailContainer);
}
```

}

Comment: @CookieMonster : let me knw your cmt.

Comment: Wouldn't `setContentView(detailContainer);` just add it to the current activity? I pass the layout to other methods as well

Comment: setContentView(detailContainer); sets activity layout

Comment: I don't want to set the activity layout, I just want to change the settings for this specific LinearLayout view and pass it to another class that extends this class.

Answer (score 0):

You´re using the wrong LayoutParams for Button, this is working

```
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_test);
    Button buttonWithMessage= new Button(this);
    buttonWithMessage.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams test = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) buttonWithMessage.getLayoutParams();
    test.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
    buttonWithMessage.setLayoutParams(test);
    buttonWithMessage.setText("TEST");
    relativeLayout.addView(buttonWithMessage);
```

Comment: This is the view I am adding it to `LinearLayout detailContainer = new LinearLayout(this);`, I'm not using any relative layouts in the app so far.

Comment: doesn´t matter the important part is creating realativelayout params for the button, you can add the button to any layout